# Why does included layouts suggestions are not coming while working with Databinding? [Not solved]

Tags: android

Only activity_main binding suggestions coming, but not content_main. can anybody please help what's going wrong? can anyone give me why it's not happening? I tried with `binding.included.`.... not coming

Code

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="UserViewModel"
            type="com.lifetrenz.lifetrenz_gcc_doctorapp.viewmodel.UserViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/included"
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="683dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/included"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.554"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

content_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.719"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="31dp">


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
 binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    binding.setUserViewModel(userViewModel);
```

relative_layout and textview binding suggestion not coming in MainActivity.

Already tried Invalidate cache/restart!

NOTE: If I'll move code from content_main to main_activity and remove include and all suggestions are coming.

Comment: try to give the main_content constraint layout an id. and call it binding.id

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi tried. not getting suggestion

Comment: can you post the updated layout code. It will come surely.

Comment: @thamim That is updated only!

Answer (score 0):

As @FahadAlotaibi said it will show surely.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/wholeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/included"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="683dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/included"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.554"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In Java:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

binding.wholeLayout.textView.setText("");
```

[image]

Comment: what you did? just double check! whole layout or included?

Comment: set the id(wholeLayout) for constraintLayout and access the id using binding. wholeLayout and access the textview in include layout binding.wholeLayout.textview

Comment: I tried both way. it's not coming. I tried with wholelayout and included both id